# Why is function CreateWebHostBuilder() created?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

When creating a ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API, Visual Studio 2019 creates this code:

```
namespace myapi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Why the heck is it creating a function `CreateWebHostBuilder` ? 
Why does it not just create a code as follows?

```
namespace myapi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().Build().Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `CreateWebHostBuilder` method is used by the Entity Framework Core tools, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0#set-up-a-host):

> The code that calls `CreateDefaultBuilder` is in a method named `CreateWebHostBuilder`, which separates it from the code in `Main` that calls `Run` on the builder object. This separation is required if you use [Entity Framework Core tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/). The tools expect to find a `CreateWebHostBuilder` method that they can call at design time to configure the host without running the app. An alternative is to implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`. For more information, see [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation).

If you're not using EF Core, you can collapse it into the `Main` method, as you've suggested.

Comment: It's also used by the test host, if you run integration tests against the API where it starts the app in-memory.